# propertyregex not able to capture numbers

Tags: regex, ant, ant-contrib

```
 <propertyregex
      property="number"
      input="dev01"
      regexp="([^a-z])"
      select="\0" />
```

`<echo message="number is : ${number}"/>`

Expected output is: 02

but getting an output: 0

I even tried `regexp="([^a-z]*)"`

getting same output as 0.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just try \d*?

Comment: @ Dgrin91, please put suggested solutions into answer field.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <propertyregex
      property="number"
      input="dev01"
      regexp="\d*"
      select="\0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use `\d*`. `\d` is a character class that includes digits. Its is equivolent to `[0-9]`. So your final answer would be:

```
<propertyregex
      property="number"
      input="dev01"
      regexp="\d*"
      select="\0" />
```